# Oxidation of naphthalene with KMnO4

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, aromatic-compounds

> What is the product when naphthalene is oxidized by alkaline (or acidic) solutions of $\ce{KMnO4}$?

Some possible reactions show up in a google search, but they have no references:

1. Naphthalene to phthalic acid by alkaline $\ce{KMnO4}$:
   [image]
2. Another product on oxidation of napthalene by alkaline $\ce{KMnO4}$:
   [image]

If possible, please include the reaction mechanisms in the answer as well.

Comment: Quick search on Reaxys shows that both the products you've already listed have been made, also plus 2-formylbenzoic acid. Some are from 19th-century *Chem. Ber.* articles, which I'm not inclined to look up.

Comment: @orthocresol , Is there a reaction mechanism? If not, can you post this as answer?

Comment: will the 2nd reaction happen? As far as i know, the 2nd reaction will only happen to triple bonds.

Comment: Here is a reference: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0045653510001906

Comment: The ketoacid in 2 is oxidized to phthalic acid by high valence manganese. Derivatize ArCOCO2H as ArCOCO2Mn(+7). Move electrons from the sigma C-C bond toward Mn+7.which forms ArCO+ , CO2 and Mn+5. The acylium species is captured by base. Alternatively, base attacks the keto group of the derivatized Mn+7 species, which upon collapse, moves electrons toward Mn+7 forming o-phthalic acid.

Comment: jchps.com/issues/Volume%2010_Issue%201/40-0581116.pdf. This link has a mechanism for the first reaction. However, the conditions are not clear. As for the second product, is can be observed in multiple sources (but no mechanism): http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=cv2p0523 and https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/j150083a001. From what I am getting, it is likely the first product is in acidic conditions while the second one is in basic conditions. The mechanism for the second one isn't too clear though.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti For #1 in basic media, there are old references like [1907JPhysChem93](https://doi.org/10.1021/j150083a001). For running the reaction in acidic media, you find _via_ google e.g. [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312117264_Kinetic_and_mechanistic_studies_of_the_oxidation_of_naphthalene_by_potassium_permanganate_in_aqueous_acetic_medium), too.

Comment: @Shoubhik RMaiti For #2, This [may](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286367230_Naphthalene_oxidation_and_reduction_reactions) help(I mean maybe.. Just maybe, since it is Russian I think). Since the product in the #2 matches the one on the page 168

Answer (score 6):

I already made a comment about some of what I am about to say but I will provide a partial answer. I say partially because I could not find any mechanism for the second product. However, from literature, what I found was that in acidic conditions, $\ce{KMnO4}$ will oxidize naphthalene into the first product, phthalic acid<sup>1</sup>. In basic/alkaline conditions, $\ce{KMnO4}$ will oxidize naphthalene into Phthalonic Acid<sup>2</sup>. The results also agree from other papers. The proposed mechanism for the acidic solution reaction is here (taken from the paper in the first link):
[image]

It is essentially the same mechanism for the cleavage of a double bond but it happens in two positions in naphthalene. Note this is the mechanism for $\ce{KMnO4}$ oxidative cleavage:

[image]

Also note that the mechanism in the first image was based on a 2017 paper studying the kinetics of the reaction and then formulating a mechanism. So this reaction is still being studied. Along the same lines, I could not find the mechanism for the reaction of $\ce{KMnO4}$ and naphthalene in alkaline conditions. I would assume that its mechanism is still being researched.

**References**

1. https://www.jchps.com/issues/Volume%2010_Issue%201/40-0581116.pdf
2. The Oxidation of Naphthalene to Phthalonic Acid by Alkaline Solutions of Permanganate, R. Arthur Daly, The Journal of Physical Chemistry **1907** 11 (2), 93-106, DOI: [10.1021/j150083a001](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/j150083a001)
3. http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=cv2p0523
4. https://www.acros.com/_rainbow/pdf/oxidation_brochure_manga.pdf
5. http://studymaterial.unipune.ac.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/123456789/8059/1/POLYNUCLEAR%20HYDROCARBONS.pdf