# Reaction of naphthalene with sodium dichromate/sulfuric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, organic-oxidation

I recently came across a question where naphthalene undergoes oxidation with sodium dichromate in presence of sulfuric acid. The given options were benzoic acid, phthalic acid, decalin, and tetralin.

[image: Reaction of naphthalene with sodium dichromate/sulfuric acid]

I assumed the reaction to be similar to that of the reaction between potassium permanganate under acidic conditions, yielding phthalic acid.
This reaction was described in
[Oxidation of naphthalene with KMnO4](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88668/oxidation-of-naphthalene-with-kmno4).

Could anyone please clarify the reaction, whether my assumption is correct, and explain the mechanism?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the reaction conditions.

I suspect the answer the question setter wants to see is phthalic acid, but the true answer is none of these. I have found multiple references (such as this [US Patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2402226A/en) and this [Org. Syn prep](http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV4P0698)) that refer to the production of naphthoquinones by oxidation of naphthalenes with high valent Chromium reagents under acid conditions.